# How to silently install Visual Studio Code on Windows?

Tags: chocolatey, visual-studio-code

Current observed behavior:

- invoke VSCodeSetup.exe
- install happens with no prompting
- Code *opens*, which was a little surprising for a Windows package

I'm creating a Chocolatey package, and ideally, what I want:

- no banner during install (but can live with it)
- Code can't open! That's a deal breaker for a package manager, guys!

I realize that the thing just shipped v 0.1.0 and what I want may not be possible, but just wanted this out in the open in case

1. it is possible, and
2. others can help me figure out how.

Comment: If you want the installer changed, vote this guy up: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7768155-change-installer-to-accomodate-automation-requirem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it uses Squirrel, you can just use `-s` https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/92e7af66b1593f951527dd88289a4ed1bee4bcdd/src/Update/Program.cs#L109

Also https://chocolatey.org/packages/VisualStudioCode#files

Answer (score 1):

[Since December](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/860) the official installer supports this with the added commandline

```
/MERGETASKS=!runcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of 1.10.x the -s switch no longer works on Windows 10.  Use /SILENT, however, this still shows a dialog form with a "Cancel" button, when invoked interactively.  Include /mergetasks=!runcode to suppress the launch after installation is completed.  Tested on Windows 10 build 15058.