# How to install Visual Studio Code silently (without auto open when installation ends)?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, visual-studio-code, silent-installer

I found the option to install silently from command line (`vscode-installer.exe /VERYSILENT`), **BUT** it still opens automatically at the end of the installation, thus making unattended installation on multiple computers inconvenient.

I checked [**Inno Setup's documentation**](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) (that's what the Visual Studio Code installer uses), but there's nothing related to disabling Visual Studio Code autostart (even on very silent installation).

There might be a way by using `/COMPONENTS`, `/TASKS` or `/MERGETASKS`, but for that I need to know what is already available for use.

**Is there a way to make it install completely silently?**

Comment: Related: [How to silently install Visual Studio Code on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973213/1364007)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a [hidden task `runcode`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/860), that gets automatically selected for silent installations. To unselect the `runcode` task, use the [`/MERGETASKS=!runcode` option](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=MERGETASKS).

```
VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.86.2.exe /VERYSILENT /MERGETASKS=!runcode
```

*(Credits for the `/MERGETASKS=!runcode` go to [@RobertWigley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888490/robert-wigley))*

---

The above is based on [`build/win32/code.iss`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/main/build/win32/code.iss#L83-L103) in the GitHub repo:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "runcode"; Description: "{cm:RunAfter,{#NameShort}}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:Other}"; Check: WizardSilent

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#ExeBasename}.exe"; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#NameLong}}"; Tasks: runcode; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall; Check: ShouldRunAfterUpdate
Filename: "{app}\{#ExeBasename}.exe"; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#NameLong}}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall; Check: WizardNotSilent
```

Answer (score 5):

I found to run within Powershell I used Start-Process, Execute-Process seemed to be deprecated for me.

The below is the line I use.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "path/to/vscode/VSCodeUserSetup-x64.exe" -Argument "/VERYSILENT /MERGETASKS=!runcode"
```

Comment: I found some additional arguments helpful:  '/verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /mergetasks=!runcode,desktopicon'.

Answer (score 0):

`Execute-Process` is a built-in function for [PowerShell Application Deployment Toolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/) (PSADT) and the `-Parameters` parameter is also not a standard parameter, but part of that custom function.

Instead, use `Start-Process -FilePath "VSCode.exe" -ArgumentList "/VERYSILENT /MERGETASKS=!runcode"`

You can pass any of the arguments in the `-ArgumentList`

Answer (score -1):

Execute-Process -Path "VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.30.1.exe" -Parameters "/VERYSILENT /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS

you can use this for PowerShell installation.